# Neural Network 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning

I was trying to use a simple NN on a matrix of chemical compositions of 24 elements a total of 270 analysis (25X270 including the label). However when I am running the gradient descent it shows the error 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

```
data = np.array(data)
m, n = data.shape
np.random.shuffle(data) 

data_dev = data[0:60].T
Y_dev = data_dev[0]
Y_dev = np.array(Y_dev, dtype=np.float_)
X_dev = data_dev[1:n]
X_dev = preprocessing.normalize(X_dev)

data_train = data[60:m].T
Y_train = data_train[0]
Y_train = np.array(Y_train, dtype=np.float_)
X_train = data_train[1:n]
X_train = preprocessing.normalize(X_train)
_,m_train = X_train.shape
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef86I.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoJZn.png)

This is the error that I got:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlgeO.png)

I´ve tried the code with the MNIST dataset (Changing the structure of the first W1 to 10,784 and dividing each pixel data by 255 to avoid any conflict) and it works well. I also check the dtype of the arrays and it is the same (float64) I don't know why is there a problem with my data.

Answer (score 0):

What the type of `Y` array?

If it is a `float64` then the problem is that Y.max() returns float value but you need integers when you define the sizes of arrays. so you need to change:

```
Y = np.array([1, 2, 3], np.float64)
one_hot_Y = np.zeros((Y.size, Y.max() + 1))  # will not work
```

to

```
one_hot_Y = np.zeros((Y.size, int(Y.max()) + 1))
```

Or convert the type of `Y` to int: `Y.astype(int)`